# Sort Numpy array by subfield

Tags: numpy

I have a structured `numpy` array, in which one of field has subfields:

```
import numpy, string, random
dtype = [('name', 'a10'), ('id', 'i4'),
         ('size', [('length', 'f8'), ('width', 'f8')])]
a = numpy.zeros(10, dtype = dtype)
for idx in range(len(a)):
    a[idx] = (''.join(random.sample(string.ascii_lowercase, 10)), idx,
              numpy.random.uniform(0, 1, size=[1, 2]))
```

I can easily get it sorted by any of fields, like this:

```
a.sort(order = ['name'])
a.sort(order = ['size'])
```

When I try to sort it by a structured field ('size' in this example), it is effectively getting sorted by the first subfield ('length' in this example). However, I would like to have my elements sorted by 'height'. I tried something like this, but it does not work:

```
a.sort(order = ['size[\'height\']']))
ValueError: unknown field name: size['height']
a.sort(order = ['size', 'height'])
ValueError: unknown field name: height
```

Therefore, I wonder, if there is a way to accomplish the task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe this is what you want:

```
a[a["size"]["width"].argsort()]
```